# Safety using a step-down transformer (240VAC to 110VAC) with a heated pad?

Tags: transformer, safety

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm trying to be more safe than sorry and don't have a lot of experience with high-voltage electronics.

I have a special small heated pad (for use on the body) with specifications 120VAC - 27W - 60Hz.

In my country we use 240VAC, so I thought I'd buy a decent step-down transformer (also does step-up.) It's fused (fine fuse, don't know how fast it is,) continuous power at 160W (well above the required 27W,) but there is no frequency conversion (shouldn't be a problem for a heated pad, should it?)

Thinking about this, a 'be careful' nag popped up.

Is there a possible safety issue I'm missing?

Comment: I'd be concerned about how you might prevent 120 volts live and neutral coming into contact with a human body. I mean, shouldn't you be using some kind of low voltage heater instead? Leave a data sheet link to the pad please.

Comment: Be careful of amazon/ebay convertors and transformers, some of them greatly exaggerate their specifications. I have one labeled 65W that weighs maybe 200 grams, the same size as a 12 watt wall wart. Sometimes they'll get away with it, if you're just using a shaver or a stick blender for a short time. Buy something several times the rating you need.

Comment: You are correct in saying that the frequency 50/60Hz doesn't matter for a resistive load like a heat pad. But like the other two comments, I would be worried at putting even 110V heating pad in contact with the human body. It would be far safer if you use a low voltage one, say 6 or 12V. As another comment says, there's an awful lot of dangerous junk out there on Ebay and similar sites. There are plenty of videos on YouTube where various items are dismantled and their dangerous faults discussed. If you must use the pad a transformer for that rating should weigh approximately 1kg.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your super-fast replies guys! The heated pad is a UL Certified, FDA registered Class II Medical Device by Sunbeam, so it's not some shady manufacturer. I very much agree with buying decent transformers, so I bought a solid one from a respectable German manufacturer (weighs about 1.75 kg or 3.85 pounds). As far as heated pads or blankets go, I'm pretty cautious. But a lot of them just plug into regular sockets (I have two others for 240VAC), so how are these made and kept safe?